# RESEARCH Q: Finding the n-th derivative of the Quotient Rule

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I am a sophomore at a community college so if my writing sounds a bit gibberish please ask for clarification.

My goal is to find a sequence/series that can summarize the nth derivative of a $u/v $ function.

The reason why I am posting this on stack exchange is to try to see if this technique has already been used by someone else and to analyze some of the responses in order to try different techniques/approaches for achieving my goal. Therefore I am only going to show a portion of my research in order to prevent any bias.

Let $u$, $v$ and $k$ be functions of $x$, and let $i$, $a$, $e$ and $n$ represent real positive integers.  $u$ and $v$ can have derivatives of order $a$ or $e$, represented by  $u^{(a)}$, $u^{(e)}$,  $v^{(a)}$ and $v^{(e)}$.

I created the function $\mu(a,e,n+i) =  (-1)^i(\frac{(n+i-1)!}{(n-1)!})\frac{v^{(e)}u^{(a)} - u^{(e)}v^{(a)}}{k^{n+i}} $; by taking the derivative with respect to $x$ of $\mu(a,e,n+i)$, if I could figure out how to write complex fractions, I could prove

$ \frac{d \hspace{1pt} \mu(a,e,n+i)}{dx}  = \mu(a+1,e,n+i) + \mu(a,e+1,n+i) + k^{(1)}\mu(a,e,n+i+1)$

My question is: what is the best approach for solving this sequence/series after knowing this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by a $u/v$ function, but if you are looking into finding the general $n$-th derivative of any function, fractional calculus can shed some light on how to proceed.

Comment: Please try to use $\LaTeX$.  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/  It makes it easier for most of us when we're looking at the syntax.

Comment: http://www3.nd.edu/~msen/Teaching/UnderRes/FracCalc.pdf While some of it is confusing, you may find some useful methods.

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule

Comment: u/v in undergrad represents the quotient rule for derivatives

Comment: @Jon Use the "General Leibniz rule" winther has presented, and attempt to calculate $\left(\frac uv\right)^{(n)}$ using $\frac1v=t$ and applying the 'rule'

Comment: @SimpleArt that sounds simple but it doesn't take into account the v^n at the bottom of the equation for example if f = u/v then f' = (vu'-uv')/v^2

Comment: I suggested some edits to your question, hoping they would make it clearer so you can get more responses. If the edit is accepted, please let me know if any of it is not what you meant.

Comment: @Jon Use Faa di Bruno's formula, as Danial McLaury notes.

Answer (score 4):

To summarize what's being suggested in the comments, we have
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}\right)
= \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(u(x) \cdot \frac{1}{v(x)}\right)
= \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left(u(x) \cdot v(x)^{-1}\right)$$
By the general product rule, this is equal to
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{d^{n-k}}{dx^{n-k}} u(x) \cdot \frac{d^k}{dx^k} v(x)^{-1}$$
So the problem reduces to finding the $k$-th derivative of $v(x)^{-1}$.  This can be done by applying [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula) for the n-th derivative of a composition of functions.